# How can I optimize this python program just to make it 0.2-0.1 secs faster? Dijkstra algorithm

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, dijkstra

```
import time
class DJ:
    def __init__(self, roads, n):
        self.roads, self.n=roads,n

    #Dijkstra with mod for a pathway from vertex a to c 
    #returns dist of a to all points if arg c is 0    
    def dis(self,a,c):
        spset,dist,prev,path,k=[],['d'],['d'],[],[]

        dist.extend([float("inf")]*self.n)
        prev.extend([0]*self.n)
        dist[a]=0

        if a==c:
            return [a]

        while len(spset)!=self.n:
            k=[dist[m] for m in range(1,self.n+1) if m not in spset]
            for i in range(1,self.n+1):
                if dist[i]==min(k) and i not in spset:
                    s=i
                    spset.append(s)
                    break
            for i in range(1, self.n+1):
                if self.roads[s][i]==1 and dist[s]+1<dist[i]:
                    dist[i]=dist[s]+1
                    prev[i]=s
                    if i==c:
                        path.append(c)
                        while c!=a:
                            path.append(prev[c])
                            c=prev[c]
                        return path
            k=[]
        return dist
```

Is there any way I can optimize this function, on first glance? I'm not really experienced in python. Just started a week ago. I just need this to run about 0.1 to 0.2 secs faster. It's based on the spt algo Dijkstra.  I'm sorry for being so less descriptive.

eg:
if the vertices(edges) are:

```
(1,2)
(2,3)
(3,4)
(4,5)
```

`dis(1,3)` should return the pathway from 1 to 3 i.e `[1,2,3]`, otherwise if, c is 0, i.e `dis(2,0)` should return distance of 2 from all points i.e `[1,0,1,2,3]`

Comment: Shorten your code, which func you trying to optimize, provide an example of its input and output.

Comment: I shortened the code and added an example. Do you see anywhere, I can optimize the code?

Comment: One idea: keep an matrix and store the path you already calculated, so next time you don't need to recalc.